Renovate is updating to old version of library
Anyone has seen Renovate is creating a PR to update library version to an older one?
This is the setting for my renovate:
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "reviewersFromCodeOwners": true,
  "baseBranches": ["$default"],
  "prConcurrentLimit": 40,
  "extends": [
    "config:best-practices",
    "schedule:nonOfficeHours",
    "schedule:automergeNonOfficeHours",
    ":automergeMinor",
    ":combinePatchMinorReleases"
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "groupName": " minor dependencies",
      "groupSlug": "minor-patch",
      "matchPackagePatterns": [
        "*"
      ],
      "matchUpdateTypes": [
        "minor",
        "patch"
      ],
      "automerge": true
    }
  ]
}

And Renovate create PR to update:
Package: com.graphql-java:java-dataloader 
Type: dependencies 
Update: major 
Change: 3.3.0 -> 2022-09-12T23-25-35-08559ba 
Checking the maven repo the updated version is older than the current one. Is this because of my renovate setting?

That's a very unusual version for Maven. You could add rules to ignore such pattern for this dependency if needed.

This is probably because Renovate does not look at the date of publication, but orders versions like Maven usually does.
And in Maven logic, 3.3.0 has major version 3 and 2022-09-12T23-25-35-08559ba has major version 2022.

You are right, checking with maven versioning compare, it is true that 3.3.0 < 2022: https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/versioning/maven/
